# Disable contentEditable commands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I would make sure that a specific html element with the contentEditable HTML5 attribute, the user can not execute "commands" (for example: CTRL + B, CTRL + I, etc.). I would make this with jQuery or javascript functions.
How I can do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen for the key events and if the input matches a command, you can prevent-default it:

**Sample code** (tested in Chrome only):

```
div.addEventListener('keydown', keyHandler);

function keyHandler(e) {
  if (matchesCmd(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function matchesCmd(e) {              
  return e.ctrlKey && e.which==86; // Ctrl-v
}
```

**Demo** (tested in Chrome only): http://jsbin.com/Akejur/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I need a list of the CTRL+* commands and add it into the script, right? Thank you again

Comment: The matchesCmd method should return true if the keypress event matches a command (however you define it) and false otherwise. If any key pressed with ctrl on is a command, simply `return e.ctrlKey` and you're done. You should also look at how your library of choice abstracts events; addEventListener might not be available, the event might have properties or values differently for the same keys, etc.